# Can ElasticSearch edgeNGram tokenizer skip numbers

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to implement Autocomplete functionality using ElasticSearch and edgeNGram tokenizer. For now I am using this tokenizer configuration:

```
"tokenizer": {
            "autocomplete": {
                "type": "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 20,
                "token_chars": [
                    "letter", "digit"
                ]
            }
        },
```

If the amalyzed text contains Words and Numbers, for example, Addresses ( Steet and House number), then Numbers are tokenized as well.

I would like to tokenize only Words, and stay Numbers (lets say, words staring with Digit) intact. So Autocomplete would work on word parts and not on Number parts, only on whole numbers.

Is it possible to do it with Elastic? AFAIK I cannot combine multiple tokenizers together.

Comment: Note that you also have edge-ngram token filters, which act on each token. Hence you could have an upstream token filter that removes digits and then the edge-n-gram one kicks in

Comment: Thank You Val for the comment. I have checked  edgeNGram filter, but it seems that it works the same way as the Tokenizer. The filter does not accept "token_chars" parameter also. Still cannot figure out how to leave Numbers as "untokenized" term. Could You provide an example, please?

Comment: Did you every figure this one out?